# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage on Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, model

Im gettting this error in my view on a LinQ Statement of my Model and i dont know why

**This is my controller:**

```
namespace Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Models
{
    public class HomePosController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string txtInput)
        {
            return View("~/Views/HomePos/Index.cshtml",db.VENTA_PLATILLOS.ToList());
        }
     }
}
```

**This is my Model**

```
namespace Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Models
{
    public partial class VENTA_PLATILLOS
    {
        public System.DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Clave_PDV { get; set; }
        public int Cheque { get; set; }
        public int Linea { get; set; }
        public int Platillo { get; set; }
        public string Nombre_Platillo { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
        public decimal Precio { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public int Turno { get; set; }
        public string Nombre_Turno { get; set; }
        public int Grupo { get; set; }
        public string Nombre_Grupo { get; set; }
        public string Nombre_Pdv { get; set; }
        public string Estatus_Pla { get; set; }
        public string Estatus_Che { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**And my View:**:

```
@model ICollection<Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Models.VENTA_PLATILLOS>
<!--other code-->
<select>
    <option value="">Todos</option>
    @foreach (var item in   Model.Select(l => l.Nombre_Pdv).OrderByDescending(a=>a.Length).Distinct())
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option>
    }
</select>
```

Im getting The folling error at the 'Model.' part **"The type argument for method cannot be inferred  from usage"**
What i am doing wrong?

**UPDATED**

I solved the Problem Changing my model declaration 'ICollection' to 'List'

```
@model List<Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Models.VENTA_PLATILLOS>
```

Comment: @model ICollection<Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Models.VENTA_PLATILLOS>

Comment: Am I missing something? I cant see any member Pdv in VENTA_PLATILLOS.

Comment: Where is the `Pdv` property in model. I see a `Nombre_Pdv` and `Clave_PDV` but no `Pdv`

Comment: my bad, i chaged the Pdv to Nombre_Pdv as in model , but im stil getting the same error my model is a collection

Comment: As trouble shooting replace `View("~/Views/HomePos/Index.cshtml",db.VENTA_PLATILLOS.ToList());` with `View(db.VENTA_PLATILLOS.ToList());`

Comment: A shot in the dark here. Change `@model ICollection<Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Models.VENTA_PLATILLOS>` to `@model List<Arpon.Web.Brain.Pos.Models.VENTA_PLATILLOS>` to match what you are returning from Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be that your loop does not know what 'Type' it is iterating.  Try using an explicit cast.

```
@foreach (var item in (List<string>) Model.Select(l => l.Pdv).OrderByDescending(a=>a.Length).Distinct())
```

Comment: using your suggestion give me this error "Using the generic type List<T> requires 1 argument"

Comment: whops, forgot to add some brackets, try now and lemme know if this helps